# Execute an Action when the Enter-Key is pressed in a NSTextField?

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I have a small problem right now. I want to execute a method when the Enter key is pressed in a NSTextField. The user should be able to enter his data and a calculation method should be executed as soon as he hits the enter key.

Answer (score 84):

You can do this by setting the text field's action. In IB, wire the text field's selector to your controller or whatever object presents the IBAction you want to use.

To set it in code, send the NSTextField a `setTarget:` message and a `setAction:` message. For example, if you're setting this on your controller object in code, and your textField outlet is called myTextField:

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender
{
  // do something interesting when the user hits <enter> in the text field
}

// ...

[myTextField setTarget:self];
[myTextField setAction:@selector(someAction:)];
```

Comment: It's important to note that this won't work (at least I couldn't make it work) in IB.

Comment: The first time I tried this with Interface Builder it wasn't working. For whatever reason. The second it worked. Obviously always work in Code. Thanks for showing the way!

Comment: Except if I `tab` out of the field, it also performs the action.

Comment: citelao:  In modern XCode, the NSTextField can have different action modes.  By default, an NSTextField is set to "Send on End Editing", which sends the action whenever you stop editing it for any reason (for example, tabbing away).  But you can switch it in Interface Builder to "Send on Enter Only" (on the attributes tab, toward the bottom of the "Text Field" group of attributes), to make it only send the action when the user actually presses enter.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Dude... that's exactly what I was looking for... great hint!

Comment: Unfortunately it also sends the selector when you click the X that appears to the right of the NSSearchField. Apple's docs suggest that clicking X is the same as deleting everything and typing enter, so the selector is called so you can look for an empty NSSearchField and clear results.  If you don't like that behavior, I think the only fix is to add code similar to:
   [[[searchField cell] cancelButtonCell] setAction:@selector(clearSearchField:)];
   [[[searchField cell] cancelButtonCell] setTarget:self];

Comment: This answer is incomplete, since it only handles the interface builder case. Please consider @Raff 's answer below: it handles the programatic case as well.

Comment: Note that the programmatic way to set what @TrevorPowell mentions (send action on end editing vs only return) is to set `sendsActionOnEndEditing` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCell/sendsActionOnEndEditing)) on the text field's `cell`.

Answer (score 54):

You have to do only this

For some keys (Enter, Delete, Backspace, etc)

```
self.textfield.delegate = self;
```

and then implement this method

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)fieldEditor doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    NSLog(@"Selector method is (%@)", NSStringFromSelector( commandSelector ) );
    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:)) {
        //Do something against ENTER key

    } else if (commandSelector == @selector(deleteForward:)) {
        //Do something against DELETE key

    } else if (commandSelector == @selector(deleteBackward:)) {
        //Do something against BACKSPACE key

    } else if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) {
        //Do something against TAB key

    } else if (commandSelector == @selector(cancelOperation:)) {
        //Do something against Escape key
    }
    // return YES if the action was handled; otherwise NO
}
```

Comment: Another relevant command is `cancelOperation:` which will be triggered by the escape key.

Answer (score 33):

The **Swift 3 / 4 / 5** version of @M.ShuaibImran's solution:

First subclass your ViewController to: NSTextFieldDelegate

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {
  ...
}
```

Assign the textField delegate to the ViewController in your viewDidLoad():

```
self.textField.delegate = self
```

Include the NSTextFieldDelegate method that handles keyboard responders:

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
    if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.insertNewline(_:))) {
        // Do something against ENTER key
        print("enter")
        return true
    } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.deleteForward(_:))) {
        // Do something against DELETE key
        return true
    } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.deleteBackward(_:))) {
        // Do something against BACKSPACE key
        return true
    } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.insertTab(_:))) {
        // Do something against TAB key
        return true
    } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.cancelOperation(_:))) {
        // Do something against ESCAPE key
        return true
    }
    
    // return true if the action was handled; otherwise false
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. Just the little thing I was looking for and almost 3 years later it still works in Swift 5/Xcode 11 without any changes or Xcode recommendations.

Answer (score 26):

In your delegate (NSTextFieldDelegate), add the following:

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // See if it was due to a return
    if ( [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSTextMovement"] intValue] == NSReturnTextMovement )
    {
        NSLog(@"Return was pressed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is for situation when text field loses its focus. NOT ENTER BUTTON

Comment: Don't forget to set your delegate in .h, in code/IB and to modify textfield action to "send on Enter only" in IB.

Comment: @Gargo This is not true at least on El Capitan. Pressing Enter causes to receive this message. Either it is some validation that causes it or something else.

Answer (score 18):

It's very easy and you can do it directly from UI editor

1. Right click the Text Feild, drag Action reference to the button as shown below in the screenshot

[image]

2. Now it will give you some option as shown in screen shot below, you need to select perform click

[image]

3. Now it should look like this

[image]

**Note:** The event will be raised as soon as you press `Tab` or `Enter` key. In case you want the action should only be raised when user presses the `Enter` key then you have to do a setting. Go to the `Attribute inspector` and change the *Action* property to `Send on Enter only` as shown in screen shot below

[image]

Comment: Hi, after doing this when i am pressing enter it is selecting the whole text in the text field how to stop that?

Comment: @Vikas Bansal thanks, bro your solution worked for me.

Comment: @souvickcse I ran into the exact same issue. Did you find any solution here? It's 3.5 years later but... hail the internet :D

Comment: To be honest i forgot the issue itself, please try other solution on this question, i think your will problem will be solved

Comment: Yep... a few days later and I found a solution for the highlighted text after the action is called: Just put these three lines last: ```let resultLength = String(result).count``` (if the item to count is already a ```String```theres of course no need to convert into ```String```, then add this line: ```yourNSTextField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = NSRange(location: resultLength, length: 0)``` and then this one: ```yourNSTextField.displayIfNeeded()```
The cursor will jump right behind the last character of your presented content.

Comment: Thanks for sharing "Action – Send on enter only"!

Answer (score 4):

`NSTextFieldDelegate`'s – `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:` is your friend.

Look for the `insertNewline:` command.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although I didn't used it (I used the `setAction:` on top) I found a lot of usefull things where `insertNewline:` is.

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder - click on your NSTextField, go to the connections editor, drag from selector to your controller object - you're actions should come up!

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do that is to bind the `NSTextField` value with `NSString` property.

For Example,define a method:

```
(void)setTextFieldString:(NSString *)addressString {}
```

add bindings:

```
[textField bind:@"value" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"self.textFieldString" options:nil];
```

Enter any text and hit the return key, `setTextFieldString` will be called.