# NSTextField not noticing lost focus when pressing Tab?

Tags: cocoa, focus, nstextfield

I can't seem to find a way to get notified when an NSTextField loses focus by pressing the Tab key. I get a nice *textDidEndEditing* when clicking another control or when pressing Enter, but not if I change the focus by pressing the Tab key.

Also tried to yank *KeyDown* and *doCommandBySelector* for this purpose but I got nowhere.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention, but I tried resignFirstResponder too. This is the code I tried:

```
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    NSRunAlertPanel(@"", @"Lost Focus",@"OK", nil, nil);
    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    NSRunAlertPanel(@"", @"Got focus",@"OK", nil, nil);
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Strangely, what happens here is that when getting focus, both becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder are called one after the other. But when changing focus away from the control, neither are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a way to do it: use a window delegate to make the window return a custom field editor. This field editor keeps track of the last TextField that's been activated and calls its textDidEndEditting method when losing firstResponder itself. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>


@interface MyTextField : NSTextField
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder;
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification;
@end

@interface MyFieldEditor : NSTextView
{
    MyTextField * lastBox;
}
-(void) setLastEditBox:(MyTextField*) box;
@end

@interface MyWindowDelegate : NSWindowController 
{
    MyFieldEditor *fieldEditor;
}
@end



@implementation MyFieldEditor

-(void) setLastEditBox:(MyTextField*) box{ lastBox = box; }

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
        [self setFieldEditor:YES];

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    // Activate the last active editbox editting-end event
    if(lastBox != nil)
    {
        [lastBox textShouldEndEditing:self];
        lastBox = nil;
    }

    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}

@end


@implementation MyWindowDelegate

-(id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(id)client
{
    if(fieldEditor == nil)  // Return our special field editor
        fieldEditor = [[[MyFieldEditor alloc] autorelease] init];
    return fieldEditor;
}
@end


@implementation MyTextField

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    // We're losing first responder, inform the field editor that this was the last edit box activated
    MyFieldEditor* myTf = (MyFieldEditor*) [[self window] fieldEditor:YES forObject:self];
    [myTf setLastEditBox:self];
    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    [super textDidEndEditing:notification];
    [self setStringValue:@"RECEIVED ENDEDITING"];
}

@end




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 150);

    // Create the window
    NSWindow* window  = [[[NSWindow alloc] autorelease ] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSClosableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask
                                                      backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

    [window setDelegate:[[MyWindowDelegate alloc] autorelease]];


    MyTextField * tf = [ [[ MyTextField alloc ] autorelease] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect( 30.0, 100.0, 150.0, 22.0 ) ];
    [ [ window contentView ] addSubview: tf ];

    MyTextField * tf2 = [ [[ MyTextField alloc ] autorelease] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect( 30.0, 40.0, 150.0, 22.0 ) ];
    [ [ window contentView ] addSubview: tf2 ];

    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: window];  

    [app run];
    [pool release];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> "I get a nice textDidEndEditing when
>   clicking another control or when
>   pressing Enter, but not if I change
>   the focus by pressing the Tab key."

As of April 2011, with OS X 10.6 libs, I'm using:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

...to listen for NSTextField losing focus, and it's working correctly. Is this possible in your situation? Is it something that used to be broken, but is now fixed by Apple?

If so, it's much less code :).

Comment: Works fine for me too with 10.7 SDK, 10.6 deployment target.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do only this

For key Tab

```
self.textfield.delegate = self;
```

and then implement this method

```
- (void)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)fieldEditor doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    NSLog(@"Selector method is (%@)", NSStringFromSelector( commandSelector ) );
    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) {
        //Do something against TAB key
        //Or Call a Method
    }
}
```

or see my answer at
[Execute an Action when the Enter-Key is pressed in a NSTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995758/execute-an-action-when-the-enter-key-is-pressed-in-a-nstextfield/20369816#20369816)

Comment: When I implemented this, buttons such as ```esc``` and ```backspace```, stopped working. You actually don't need to implement the delegate method. Just connect your text field to the delegate in interface builder and make sure ```Refuses First Responder``` is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

With the understanding that I mentioned in my other post, I figured out an answer. It's a little convoluted but it works. You have to subclass both the NSTextField and the NSWindow because you need information from both to set this up. Here's the subclasses:
HMTextField.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HMTextField : NSTextField {

}

@end
```

HMTextField.m

```
#import "HMTextField.h"
#import "HMWindow.h"

@implementation HMTextField

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    [(HMWindow*)[self window] setTfBecameFirstResponder:YES];
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

HMWindow.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HMWindow : NSWindow {
    BOOL tfIsFirstResponder, tfBecameFirstResponder;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL tfBecameFirstResponder;

@end
```

HMWindow.m

```
#import "HMWindow.h"

@implementation HMWindow

@synthesize tfBecameFirstResponder;

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        tfIsFirstResponder = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSResponder *)firstResponder {
    id fr = [super firstResponder];

    if ([fr isEqualTo:[self fieldEditor:NO forObject:nil]]) {
        tfIsFirstResponder = YES;
    } else {
        if (tfIsFirstResponder && tfBecameFirstResponder) {
            NSLog(@"the text field stopped being first responder");
            tfBecameFirstResponder = NO;
        }
        tfIsFirstResponder = NO;
    }

    return fr;
}

@end
```

Make the classes and make your objects their class. You'll be notified of the first responder change from your text field where the NSLog message is in the HMWindow.m file. If you need help understanding how it works let me know.

Comment: The thing is, this is for an interactive application that has a bunch of TextFields, spinboxes and other things, and it needs to update the view each time a user stops modifying a control. That is, when the *textDidEndEditing* event fires, we update the view. And this works well, except that this event is not fired when changing focus with the Tab key.


This means we need to support several textfields per window, and we need to be notified with an event when the focus change happens, rather than querying it as we would have to do with this solution :-S

Thanks for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to indicate the appropriate time a custom NSTextFieldCell (NSCell) should draw its own bezel & focus ring (in the method [NSTextFieldCell drawWithFrame: inView]), by 'borrowing' the cell's highlight field, setting it when the text field gains focus, and clearing it when the text field loses focus (editing completes).

This technique overcomes some problems:

1. The cell can't easily determine if it has focus.
2. The cell can't easily determine which higher level component (e.g. text field or button) it belongs to to track via its parent
3. NSTextField can instantaneously resign first responder after gaining it, which could make it seem like it lost user focus when it didn't.

Since we're re-purposing the cell's "highlighted" state field, in order to communicate the focus state to the cell, be sure to return nil from the custom NSTextFieldCell's  [highlightColorWithFrame: inView:] method.

```
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@implementation CustomTextField

-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    ((NSTextFieldCell *)self.cell).highlighted = true;
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}

 -(void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    ((NSTextFieldCell *)self.cell).highlighted = false;
    [super textDidEndEditing:notification];
} 
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex answers. There is a simpler way to do it.

Don't forget to subclass your NSTextField to NotificableTextField and set its delegate to your view controller.

**NotificableTextField.h**:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@protocol NotificableTextFieldDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)textFieldStartedEditing:(NSTextField *)textField;
- (void)textFieldEndedEditing:(NSTextField *)textField;
@end

@interface NotificableTextField : NSTextField
@end
```

**NotificableTextField.m**:

```
#import "NotificableTextField.h"

@implementation NotificableTextField

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.target = self;
    self.action = @selector(inputEnd);
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL status = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if (status && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldStartedEditing:)])
        [(id<NotificableTextFieldDelegate>)self.delegate textFieldStartedEditing:self];
    return status;
}

- (void)inputEnd
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldEndedEditing:)])
        [(id<NotificableTextFieldDelegate>)self.delegate textFieldEndedEditing:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

NSTextField is a subclass of NSResponder. NSResponder has a method - (BOOL)resignFirstResponder. That will notify you when the NSTextField is no longer first responder... ie. loses focus. So subclass your NSTextField and do your stuff in there.

Comment: See updated post. I had tried that, but it doesn't behave as expected

Comment: I understand why now. A window has a field editor for all te objects in the window that require text. When you type something you're actually entering it in a field editor and not the text field itself. As such, the text field becomes the first responder and then immediately resigns as first responder because the field editor becomes the first responder.