# NSTableView triggering another action when clicked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

While learning objective-c, I've made a basic mac shopping list app with 3 interface elements: `NSTextField`, `NSButton` and `NSTableView`. The basic idea is you type something into the text field, hit the add button (or hit return) and it adds it to the table view. Everything works as expected until I click on the table view at which point it adds what ever is currently to the text field to the table view.

The only action I have is `addItem` which adds the text field's `stringValue` to `NSTableView`'s data source, an `NSMutableArray`. I've set it to be only triggered by the button and the textfield, not the `NSTableView`. When I remove the action from `NSTextField` the problem stops. Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly did you set up the action? By Ctrl-dragging from the text field to the object implementing addItem?

Comment: The question was answered, but for reference, I tried both by ctrl-dragging the text field and programmatically as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995758/execute-an-action-when-the-enter-key-is-pressed-in-a-nstextfield/996694#996694) answer. Both had the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSTextField` fires its action both when the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key *and* when it loses focus. When you click on the `NSTableView`, the `NSTextField` loses focus, so it calls its action.

If you only want it to send its action on <kbd>Enter</kbd>, there is a pop up button in the `NSTextField`'s attributes tab labeled "Action" that you can set to "Sent on Enter Only".