# How to do something when Enter-key is pressed on NSTextField

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, nstextfield

I'm writing an app for the Mac using Swift.

I write a string inside a NSTextField object and I would like to save it in a .txt file. 
I would like that to happen as soon as the user presses Enter-key. My method `.writeToFile()` is ready, I cannot figure out how to make it run as soon as that key is pressed.

I could not find a proper answer for Swift language. Thank you.

Comment: You need an outlet and a trigger action linked to your text field.

Comment: The answer is [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/995758/643383) in Swift as it is in Objective-C. Why do you need a Swift-specific answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
@IBAction func textFieldAction(sender: NSTextField) {
    print(sender.stringValue)
}
```

[image: connections inspector]

[image: attributes inspector]

Comment: It was so easy. Stupid me. Thank you for the accurate answer!

Comment: How can you change this programmatically ?