# When using NSTextFieldDelegate's – control:textView:doCommandBySelector: how do we allow/make normal performance of e.g. backspace?

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nstextfield

In another SO thread ([Execute an Action when the Enter-Key is pressed in a NSTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995758/execute-an-action-when-the-enter-key-is-pressed-in-a-nstextfield)) I saw this suggested code for executing an action on pressing Enter in an NSTextField:

```
- (void)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)fieldEditor doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    NSLog(@"Selector method is (%@)", NSStringFromSelector( commandSelector ) );
    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:)) {
        //Do something against ENTER key

    } else if (commandSelector == @selector(deleteForward:)) {
        //Do something against DELETE key

    } else if (commandSelector == @selector(deleteBackward:)) {
        //Do something against BACKSPACE key

    } else if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) {
        //Do something against TAB key
    }
}
```

But when I use this, backspace and tab no longer work as normal.  How to fix this?

I tried to comment on original post, but do not have sufficient reputation to post comments... TIA

Comment: how can we handle space ? is there any commandSelector for that as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`control:doCommandBySelector:` should return a `bool`. Return `true` if you have handled the event and you don't want the system to do any more, return `false` if you still want the system to execute its default implementation for the given `selector`. So you need to return `false` when the `selector` is the backspace or tab selector.

Comment: Thank you!  So simple.  Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: how can we handle space ? is there any commandSelector for that as well ?