# Listen for Deleting of Line in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, nstextview

How do I detect when a line (i.e. a "\n" character) is deleted in an `NSTextView`? I can easily listen for new lines using `textView:doCommandBySelector:` and listening for `"insertNewLine:"`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995758/execute-an-action-when-the-enter-key-is-pressed-in-a-nstextfield)) I can also detect deletion of characters using the same method but instead listening for `"deleteBackward:"`. However, I am not sure how to find out what character is being deleted, and therefore perform an action only when a "\n" character is deleted. Can anyone point me to the right method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this that gets the job done, but it only works if you want the `NSTextView` to always fit the size of the text exactly. 
 The way it works is every time the text in the `NSTextView` changes, you resize the `NSTextView` to fit the text exactly, using `.sizeToFit()`. What this does is it decreases the height of the view to remove any white space at the bottom of the text, or it increases the height of the view to accommodate any new text that would be otherwise outside of the view. I realized that if I saved the height of the `NSTextView` before I resized it, I could see if the height had decreased after the fact. If the height did decrease, then I knew a line had been deleted. Here is the code:

```
func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Save original height of view:
    let presize = textView.frame.size.height

    textView.sizeToFit() // Resize view so that it fits the text exactly

    if presize > textView.frame.size.height { // see if textView's new height is less than what it used to be
        // line has been deleted!
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is not as simple as listening to a "deleteLine:" method, because there isn't one, as you found out. Most probably the best way to go about it is to do the following:

1. Create an `NSTextViewDelegate` if you haven't already
2. Implement 
   `- textView:shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings:`
3. Check whether the ranges that will be affected correspond to whole lines by calling NSString's `lineRangeForRange:` or `– getLineStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:`
4. (Note: you can access the NSString of your NSTextView by calling `NSString *text = myTextView.textStorage.string;`)
5. (Another important note: Do NOT look for '\n' characters specifically because lines can be terminated by other characters, such as '\r', U+2028 (Unicode line separator), U+2029 (Unicode paragraph separator), etc.)
6. (Yet another important note: do not forget to return YES in `- textView:shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings:` to allow the change to be made.

I hope this helps.